# unable to edit pre populated textboxes using react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a form that has textboxes that are prepopulated from an WebAPI. When I try to delete the text in the textbox to make a change it doesn't delete the prepopulate text. If I try to type over the text,  I can see only the first letter of the word I'm typing in the console, but nothing changes on the UI: It' like the textbox is in readonly mode WHICH IT IS NOT

```
const Details = () => {
  const [ server, setServer] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() = > {
   getServerNames();
  }

  const getServerName = async() => {
     //gets the list of server and their details from the API
  }

  const serverNameChange = (e) => {
   setServer(e.target.value);

  }


  return (
    <div>
    { details.map((data) => {

      <input type="text" name="server" onChange={serverNameChange} value={data.serverName} />
     ))}
    </div>

  )


};
```

What am I missing to allow the users to edit the textbox? The textbox is prepopulated with data, however, it can be changed. This is only happening on textboxes that are prepopulated. I don't want to click an Edit button, I want to give the user the ability to make a change in the textbox and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

That might be due to the fact, that data.serverName never changes. It’s basically a static value. If you set the value of an Input, you have to handle the changes (when typing) in the onchange event.
From what I assume, according to your code is that you have multiple input boxes with preloaded values in them and you want to change your serverName if one of them get changed by the value that is in the textinput.

If so, map your details into a state variable:

```
const [serverNames, setServerNames] = useState(details.map( data => data.serverName));
```

Map the inputs from your state variable like so:

```
{serverNames.map((name,index) => {
  < input type="text" name="server" onChange={(e) => {updateServerState(e, index)}} value={serverNames[index]} />
 }
}
```

And your updateServerState method looks like that:

```
updateServerState(e, index) {
  let myStateData = [...serverNames];
  myStateData[index] = e.target.value;
  setServerNames(myStateData);
  setServer(e.target.value);
}
```

**Caution:** I haven‘t tested the code, just wrote it down. But that should give you an idea of how to solve your issue.

TL;DR; Never use non-state variables for a dynamic value.

Comment: I  gave this snippet a shot and it does the same thing, for some reason the textboxes aren't allowing me to type into it. If I go to F12 I can see the characters I'm typing, but on separate lines. Not sure what's going on with the form at the moment. It's happening to all of the textboxes that are prepopulated from the API such as <input type="text" value={data.value} />